# Safari Font blinking (changing weight on hover)

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

Something is wrong with Safari (10.0.1) fonts rendering. When i hover on some elements this is happen:
[image]

Some fonts are blinking (changing weight).

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Does this happen on all sites?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if i add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to `body`, it will fix problem.

Comment: If you don't know why things are fixed, then all you know is that your solution fixes the *symptom*, but not the problem.

Comment: So, do you know what the problem is? :)

Comment: I don't, I've never used safari and don't debug for it, but I know the purpose of stackoverflow, and it involves good questions and answers, not guesses that happen to work without knowing *why* they work =) (The old adage applies here: if you don't know why it works, it doesn't work. It only seems to work, and can break at any moment)